# Стилизация select вариативного товара woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Стоит задача кастомизировать селект выбора атрибута вариативного товара!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно обернуть цены в span и покрасить их в желтый цвет. Так же задать border-radius и background самому списку options. Я пытался сделать кастомный select с помощью плагинов и ванильного js, но успехом это не увенчалось, т.к. плагины создают отдельные div-ы которые в свою очередь уже не обладают функционалом необходимым заказчику. Помоги пожалуйста решить эту сложную задачу!

Comment: Select2 и прочие либы для костомизации селектов с этим справятся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За вывод select отвечает переопределяемая функция [wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/function/wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options)

Вы можете скопировать эту функцию из плагина woocommerce (wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php) и добавить в functions.php своей темы. Уже в functions.php своей темы видоизменить select как Вам нужно.

```php
if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options' ) ) {

    /**
     * Output a list of variation attributes for use in the cart forms.
     *
     * @param array $args Arguments.
     * @since 2.4.0
     */
    function wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( $args = array() ) {
        $args = wp_parse_args(
            apply_filters( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', $args ),
            array(
                'options'          => false,
                'attribute'        => false,
                'product'          => false,
                'selected'         => false,
                'name'             => '',
                'id'               => '',
                'class'            => '',
                'show_option_none' => __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' ),
            )
        );

        // Get selected value.
        if ( false === $args['selected'] && $args['attribute'] && $args['product'] instanceof WC_Product ) {
            $selected_key = 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $args['attribute'] );
            // phpcs:disable WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.Recommended
            $args['selected'] = isset( $_REQUEST[ $selected_key ] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST[ $selected_key ] ) ) : $args['product']->get_variation_default_attribute( $args['attribute'] );
            // phpcs:enable WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.Recommended
        }

        $options               = $args['options'];
        $product               = $args['product'];
        $attribute             = $args['attribute'];
        $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
        $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
        $class                 = $args['class'];
        $show_option_none      = (bool) $args['show_option_none'];
        $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' ); // We'll do our best to hide the placeholder, but we'll need to show something when resetting options.

        if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
            $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
            $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
        }

        $html  = '<select id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" data-show_option_none="' . ( $show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no' ) . '">';
        $html .= '<option value="">' . esc_html( $show_option_none_text ) . '</option>';

        if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
            if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
                // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.
                $terms = wc_get_product_terms(
                    $product->get_id(),
                    $attribute,
                    array(
                        'fields' => 'all',
                    )
                );

                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options, true ) ) {
                        $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name, $term, $attribute, $product ) ) . '</option>';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                    // This handles < 2.4.0 bw compatibility where text attributes were not sanitized.
                    $selected = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? selected( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : selected( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                    $html    .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option, null, $attribute, $product ) ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
        }

        $html .= '</select>';

        // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', $html, $args );
    }
}
```

Comment: А если я заменю select на div а options на buttons или еще что либо? Функционал останется неизменным?

Comment: @Yatupic может сломаться форма "добавить в корзину". аккуратно нужно менять, чтоб все параметры были сохранены, чтоб js обработчики не сломались и т.д.

Comment: А как лучше кастомизировать html внутри этой функции для того, что бы застилить дропдаун? Я пробовал только что изменить на кнопки, но происходит мгновенный sumbit

Comment: @Yatupic ставьте js оработчики на кнопки